# `PlotLegends` not showing correct colour

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending, style

I want to make a `Plot` with a styled line, as follows:

```
testFunc = E^((x - 2)^(3/2)/(2*Sqrt[2])); 
Plot[Style[testFunc, Darker[Red], Dashed], {x, 1, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {StringForm["f(x) = ``", testFunc]}]
```

The `PlotLegends` entry comes out the wrong colour - it accepts the dashed line, but not that it's red:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Reported the bug.

Comment: Rather than use `Style` around the function, use the `PlotStyle` option: `Plot[testFunc,  {x,  1,  10},  PlotStyle  ->  Directive[Darker[Red], Dashed],  PlotLegends  ->  Placed[{testFunc},  {0.5,  0.5}]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `Plot` does not take all the styles applied via `Style` into account. Since it does work in principle (the dashing is applied), you can simply combine the styling directives into one using [`Directive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html). This produces the expected result:

```
testFunc = E^((x - 2)^(3/2)/(2*Sqrt[2]));
Plot[
 Style[testFunc, Directive[Darker[Red], Dashed]],
 {x, 1, 10},
 PlotLegends -> {StringForm["f(x) = ``", testFunc]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Also, simply wrapping them in a list works fine for this case.